# URLRewriteFilter rule append to url 2 times

Tags: tomcat, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am facing some weird issue . Executing one rule ( last rule ) is putting to url to times before forwarding which is giving me 404 error .

web.xml content

```
    <filter>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
    <param-value>DEBUG</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <!-- FORWARD dispatcher will keep on parsing requests through rule until
     atleast one rule is applied . It sometime may lead into infinite loop
     --> 
  <!--    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>  -->
</filter-mapping>
```

My rules

```
<rule>
    <name>DepreatedUrls</name>
    <from>(/my/url2|/my/url3)</from>
    <set type="status">410</set>
    <to last="true">%{context-path}/error/410.html</to>
</rule>

<rule>
    <name>AllRemainingRequests</name>
    <note>
        This rule will block all other requests and return http error
        404 ( not supported ) and custom error message .
    </note>
    <from>(.*)</from>
    <set type="status">404</set>
    <to last="true">/error/410.html</to>
</rule>
```

All other rules are executing fine . Every rule is last rule ( last="true") .
But when last rule is executed it forwards the request to 
/error/410.html/error/410.html

I have removed most of the rule definition to keep it simple . Following is the debug logs

```
Nov 20, 2012 12:31:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: AllRemainingRequests (rule 8) run called with /some-content
Nov 20, 2012 12:31:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: matched "from"
Nov 20, 2012 12:31:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.SetAttribute DEBUG: set Set status null 404 called
Nov 20, 2012 12:31:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.SetAttribute DEBUG: setting status
Nov 20, 2012 12:31:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleExecutionOutput DEBUG: needs to be forwarded to /error/410.html/error/410.html
Nov 20, 2012 12:31:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: rule is last
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some hit and trial I found the solution .
"from" component for AllRemainingRequests is troubling . 
When I put following definition for AllRemainingRequests it works fine .

```
<rule>
    <name>AllRemainingRequests</name>
    <from>(/.*)</from> 
    <set type="status">404</set>
    <to last="true">/error/410.html</to>
</rule>
```

Only change is "/"